# Adding lines after a specific line (if exists)

Tags: .net

Right now I have this

```
 txtRTB.Text = txtRTB.Text & vbNewLine & "Text2"
```

Is there a way that I can add this line before, say, "Text1" if that line exists inside txtRTB.Text?

So for example, let's say that right now txtRTB.Text says:
Text1

I want my button, or whatever, to add "Text2" right before it like so:
Text2
Text1

Otherwise, just add it in the next line like so:

Random Text
Text2

[EDIT]
So let's say I have this in my rich text box:
Apples
Bananas
Pears

If I search for "Banana" without the "s" and find "Bananas", I want to add the line "Strawberry" before it like so:
Apples
Strawberry
Bananas
Pears

Otherwise, if "Banana" cannot be found (if "Bananas" isn't on the list, then I want to just add it at the top of the text box like so:
Strawberry
Apples
Pears

Comment: Give a specific example of what you want to do.

Comment: Done! (10char.)

Comment: Well, the example really help. However, specifications are still incomplete. Do the search text need to be alone on a line? If not, does the searched text is at the beginning of the line? Also, if there are multiple lines containing that text, do you want to insert the text before the first line that contain the text?

Comment: There will only be one line containing the text, and the search text doesn't have to be alone on a line. The line can contain the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the line number of the searched text to be able to insert it:

```vb
Dim index As Integer = txtRTB.Find("Text1")
If index > -1 Then
  index = txtRTB.GetLineFromCharIndex(index)
  index = txtRTB.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(index)
  txtRTB.Select(index, 0)
  txtRTB.SelectedText = "Text2" & vbNewLine
Else
  txtRTB.AppendText("Text2" & vbNewLine)
End If
```

Also, when adding text, use AppendText:

```vb
'txtRTB.Text = txtRTB.Text & vbNewLine & "Text2"
txtRTB.AppendText(vbNewLine & "Text2")
```

Comment: What about if Text1 cannot be found?

Comment: To me, that code seems a bit too complicate... Why not using `string.IndexOf` and `string.Insert` instead.

I do not have experience with VB.NET...

Comment: Is there a simpler way of doing the above code @Phil1970?

Comment: @Phil1970 Because I think the OP is not trying to insert the text in front of the searched text, but insert the text *the line above* the searched text.  That requires you to deal with line numbers, etc.

Comment: You have that exactly right, @LarsTech! And your code works beautifully!

Comment: @LarsTech Just out of curiosity, would it be possible to find part of the text that we're adding the line before of? So for example, if I'm trying to add the line before "Boogers", could I search for "Booger" and add the line before the result?

Comment: Well, if "Text2" and a new line are inserted, I think it would be the same result except that in my case the text would not be selected as I would have replaced the whole text...

Also there would be difference in the handling if "Text1" is not at the start of a line...

Comment: I'm so confused. So, it's not possible then to find the line (which would be unique - no second result) containing "Booger" and adding Text2 before "Boogers"?

Comment: @Phil1970 The way the OP phrased the question, there could be a line of text that goes `abc abc Text1`.  The OP wants to insert `Text2` the line above where  `Text1` is found.  Your IndexOf only gets you the position of `Text1`, not the beginning of that line.

Comment: @lolikols Still not clear what you are asking.  You want to insert "Booger" the line above an existing line that contains "Booger"?

Comment: @LarsTech, for me it is not clear... He says "if that line" exists so I would assume that "Text1" would be the **only** text of that line. In any case, I ask him to clarify those edge cases.

Comment: @LarsTech No, so let's say the textbox contains "Boogers". Is it possible to find "Booger" without the "s" and still identify the line that contains "Boogers" and then add "Text2" before that line?

Comment: @Phil1970 Lars actually has it right. I'm very poor at explaining myself, but he knows what I'm getting at.

Comment: @lolikols Yes, it will work.  Why don't you try it?  The problem though is when you start searching for text that can be found in too many places.

Comment: As far as I understand the "Booger" example, the code should works as expected. I understand that a line contains "Boogers" but you use "Booger" as the search text, then obviously that line would be found as "Booger" is a part of "Boogers" and the only requirement is to find the first line that contains specified text (anywhere in the line) and insert text on the line above if such line exist (and at the end otherwise). So if this is not what you want, give a specific example, what you want and what you get instead.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to find or see if string contains inside another string?

If yes, then try following:-

```
String valueTxtRTB = txtRTB.Text

     if (valueTxtRTB.Contains("Text1"))
        {  
            // Do Something // 
        }
```

Comment: Well, probably `IndexOf` if he want to do something at that position...