# Background worker Picturebox gif

Tags: vb.net

I have a picturebox with a gif (the gif works). My program is written to open up a document file that is located on a drive on the other side of the country, so it takes some time.

I have set `picturebox.visible = true` when the program starts the connection process, but the gif does not animate during this process; but only when idling.

A Google search led me to the background worker control, but in all the examples I found, I could not find one that could either:

1. Just have the gif running in a background worker permanently (I assume this wouldn't use up too much memory, as it is just a gif)

   or
2. Have the gif animate while the application is connecting

Can anyone help?

From the comments, I'm assuming that this entire thing needs to be in a backgroundworker.dowork, but I just keep getting errors because I'm changing controls here.

     Private Sub btnLoad_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLoad.Click

```
    'Displaying "Loading"
    picLoading.Visible = True
    tblMain.Visible = False

    'If the application has loaded at least one sheet
    If FirstLoad = 2 Then
        worksheet.Cells(1, 31).Value = ""
        workbook.Save()
        workbook.Close(False) 
    End If

    Filter = cmbFilter.Text

    'Go to page 1
    CurrentPage = 0

    workbook = APP.Workbooks.Open(Path & "\" & Filter & ".xlsx")
    worksheet = workbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    If Convert.ToString(worksheet.Cells(1, 31).Value) <> "" Then
        MsgBox("The sheet for " & Filter & " is currently being used by " & Convert.ToString(worksheet.Cells(1, 31).Value) & ".")
        workbook.Close(False)
    Else
        FirstLoad = 2 'Indicate that the application has loaded at least one sheet
        worksheet.Cells(1, 31).Value = User
        'Make all textboxes and comboboxes visible = false
        txtSearch.Visible = False : btnSort.Visible = False : btnSortUrgency.Visible = False : btnSave.Visible = False : btnPrevious.Visible = False : btnNext.Visible = False
        Label1.Visible = False
        Label2.Visible = False

        'Count entries and calculate how many pages there are
        Entries = worksheet.Range("B1048576").End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row 'Count how many entries there are (the first row always counts as an entry)

        TotalPages = Math.Ceiling(Entries / 8) - 1 'Calculate how many pages there are
        If TotalPages = (Entries / 8) - 1 Then
            TotalPages = TotalPages + 1
        End If

        'Determine how many entries are on the last page
        LastEntries = Entries
        While LastEntries > 8 'Keep subtracting by 8 to determine how many entries are going to be on the last page
            LastEntries = LastEntries - 8
        End While


        'Add categories for the Urgency comboboxes
        Me.cmbUrgency1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed
        Me. cmbUrgency1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
        Me. cmbUrgency1.ItemHeight = 15
        Me. cmbUrgency1.BeginUpdate()
        cmbUrgency1.Items.Clear()
        Me. cmbUrgency1.Items.Add("1")
        Me. cmbUrgency1.Items.Add("2")
        Me. cmbUrgency1.Items.Add("3")
        Me. cmbUrgency1.Items.Add("4")
        cmbUrgency1.EndUpdate()
        Me. cmbUrgency2.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed
        Me. cmbUrgency2.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
        Me. cmbUrgency2.ItemHeight = 15
        Me. cmbUrgency2.BeginUpdate()
        cmbUrgency2.Items.Clear()
        Me. cmbUrgency2.Items.Add("1")
        Me. cmbUrgency2.Items.Add("2")
        Me. cmbUrgency2.Items.Add("3")
        Me. cmbUrgency2.Items.Add("4")
        cmbUrgency2.EndUpdate()
        Me. cmbUrgency3.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed
        Me. cmbUrgency3.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
        Me. cmbUrgency3.ItemHeight = 15
        Me. cmbUrgency3.BeginUpdate()
        cmbUrgency3.Items.Clear()
        Me. cmbUrgency3.Items.Add("1")
        Me. cmbUrgency3.Items.Add("2")
        Me. cmbUrgency3.Items.Add("3")
        Me. cmbUrgency3.Items.Add("4")
        Urgency3.EndUpdate()
        Me.Urgency4.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed
        Me.Urgency4.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
        Me.Urgency4.ItemHeight = 15
        Me.Urgency4.BeginUpdate()
        Urgency4.Items.Clear()
        Me.Urgency4.Items.Add("1")
        Me.Urgency4.Items.Add("2")
        Me.Urgency4.Items.Add("3")
        Me.Urgency4.Items.Add("4")
        Urgency4.EndUpdate()

        Dim DataCollection As New AutoCompleteStringCollection()
        txtBlank.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
        txtBlank.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
        AddItems(DataCollection)
        txtBlank.AutoCompleteCustomSource = DataCollection
        txtBlank2.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
        txtBlank2.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
        AddItems(DataCollection)
        txtBlank2.AutoCompleteCustomSource = DataCollection
        txtBlank3.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
        txtBlank3.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
        AddItems(DataCollection)
        txtBlank3.AutoCompleteCustomSource = DataCollection
        txtBlank3.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
        txtBlank3.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
        AddItems(DataCollection)
        txtBlank3.AutoCompleteCustomSource = DataCollection
       workbook.Save()
        Call DisplayInfo()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The gif will animate if UI is not being locked. Picturebox just render gif without any extra options. Use a background worker to prevent UI from freezing thus showing the gif

Comment: Well, all the guides/questions online have responses such as "move this to a different thread", but I'm having a lot of trouble finding any step by step tutorial on how to accomplish what I'm trying to do. Are there any really helpful links that you know of?

Comment: Basically you put the connecting procedure under BackgroundWorker.DoWork() method. All on that method runs without freezing the UI, so any control in the form including the picturebox will work as intended. When you have all that code, you call it using BackgroundWorker.RunAsync().

Comment: Oh! Thank you - that makes so much sense! Can you put that in as a response so I can mark it as answer?

Comment: Ah, shoot. Just ran into an error. So part of the UI freeze I guess, included the adjustment of controls, and the application is giving me an error: "Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Comment: You have to show us your code for us to help you.

Comment: @lolikols while using a BackgroundWorker, it works, well in background, so your UI is not accesible within it. You will have to pass some variables i.e. textboxbox's values and such. The only way that BW and UI can communicate are with the ReportProgress method.

Comment: Added code. Pretty much that entire thing needs to be in a background worker, I guess.

Comment: I was expecting to see your backgroundworker code...

Comment: Haha sorry LarsTech. I put the entire contents in that sub into my backgroundworker.dowork.

Comment: The only code that goes into the DoWork method is the long processing stuff.  Basically, all the GUI stuff (accessing or updating controls) does not belong in the DoWork method.  You would have to figure out how to separate all that stuff.

Comment: Ah, I see. That makes a lot of sense! I think you've actually helped me on a different question I had some time ago. Your name looks very familiar. Can you make an answer thing so I can mark it as answer?

Comment: I helped you with [Adding lines after a specific line (if exists)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40684949/719186).  I don't see how my comment can be converted into a useful answer on this question though.  You can either post your own answer or just delete this question since there are a lot of resources here regarding how to code the BackgroundWorker.